# Regex - Removing a number after one parameter

Tags: c#, regex, replace

So I have this string: "ID:300,Order:1,Number:30.99,Other:null}". I'm using c#.

I would like to use a regex to hide the "30.99" from the Number "parameter", and replace it with *** for security reasons, but I i'm still new with regex and can't figure it out.

The "Number" can be any decimal form 0 to 999999999.......

The final result would be "ID:300,Order:1,Number:***,Other:null}"

Somebody can help me on this one?

Comment: Can it also be `.01` for instance?

Comment: Is this perhaps a snippet of JSON?

Comment: @sixlettervariables no, this is not legal JSON since member names must be JSON strings

Comment: Well it's for logging. It's a serialize json string, with some trimmed characters.

Comment: What library are you using to serialize this JSON? You could perhaps use an Attribute on the property to cause it to NOT be serialized.

Comment: @iPeo so, you serialize JSON to a string and then alter that string so that it turns into non legal JSON? ;) Anyway, why not just manipulate your JSON so that the value for the `Number` member is `"*"`?

Comment: It WAS a serialize json string, before the "\" stripping. But it's not an actual issue in this case. It is now resolved thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Regex.Replace:

```
string s = Regex.Replace( 
    "ID:300,Order:1,Number:30.99,Other:null",
    @"(?<=Number:).*?(?=,|$)",
    m => "*" );
```

Comment: Yup! It does. My bad! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
(?<=\bNumber:)\d+(\.\d+)?
```

with a single `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Unliked the marked answer whose result is a single * (ID:300,Order:1,Number:*,Other:null) this one replaces all numbers and period with *.

```
Console.WriteLine(
         Regex.Replace("ID:300,Order:1,Number:30.99,Other:null}",
                     @"(?<Text>Number\:)(?<Digits>[^,]+)",
                     new MatchEvaluator((mtch) =>
                           {
                              return mtch.Groups["Text"].Value + Regex.Replace( mtch.Groups["Digits"].Value, @".", "*");
                           }))
                           );

// Result:
// ID:300,Order:1,Number:*****,Other:null}
```